# Correct signatures for composed functions

Tags: haskell, types, signature

Say I have the following function:

```
--count number of an item in a list
count :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Double
count x []     = 0.0
count x (y:ys) = (is x y) + count x ys
```

and

```
--returns 1 if items match, else 0
is :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Double
is x y
    | x == y    = 1.0
    | otherwise = 0.0
```

and

```
--compute length of the list
len :: [a] -> Double
len []     = 0.0
len [x]    = 1.0
len (x:xs) = 1.0 + len xs
```

I would like to use this method to generate a function that generates a normalized count:

```
--generates frequency of item in list
ncount :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Double
ncount x [] = 0.0
ncount x y  = norm * (count x y)
    where
    norm = 1.0 / len y
```

I'm just curious to see how signatures in this case should be handled. `count` has the signature `(Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Double`, but should `ncount` have that as well? On one hand if `a` is not in `Eq` when calling `ncount`, the subsequent call to `count` will fail. On the other hand `ncount` never tests for equality.

Sorry, left out `is` and `len`.:w

Comment: Omitting `Eq` constraint is an error (which is pretty easy to check).

Comment: I was trying to get an idea of how to handle signatures for composed functions. In general, should the signature should explicitly match the types of all functions that the function in question calls?

Comment: How is `is` defined? (You use it in the last line of `count`.) Also, by `len` I assume you mean `length`?

Comment: why should it match all functions? you can call `count` with say some default argument say `5 and [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. Then the type of `ncount` will not need any `Eq` instance.

Comment: In an indirect way `ncount` does test for equality as it is calling a function which does that. Think of the situation when compiler decides to inline `count` inside `ncount`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it's best to give each function the most polymorphic (i.e., the most all-encompassing) type signature that it can accept. There's always the chance that you'll find another use for the function somewhere else.

I find it very helpful to:

1. Code the function without a type signature.
2. Decide what type signature *I* think it should have.
3. Ask GHCi what it thinks the type signature should be, using the `:t` command.
4. Compare (2) with (3).

This accomplishes two things. First, GHCi may suggest a broader type signature than I originally wrote the function for. Normally the broader type signature is better. Second, it verifies that the function is doing what I intended it to do. This sometimes highlights a bug in my implementation.

Of course, there are times when a narrower type signature is more appropriate. Even though the computation can be performed for various types, maybe it only "makes sense" for some types. But in practice, I seldom find that to be the case. Another reason is performance issues, as pointed out by Satvik.

Comment: Its not always true that the most generic type is better. GHC can perform some optimizations if the type is specialized and that might have huge performance improvements. Thats why people use the `Specialize` pragma.

Comment: @Satvik: Modified my answer accordingly.